# float variables in c programming

Tags: c

1.I have the float variable x=3.1415926535. I have to show the number 3.1415. If I printf("%0.4f",x), I get the result 3.1416.
2. I have the decimal variable x=5 (00000101 in binary). How can I change the value of a certain bit in this number?

Comment: It's best to ask one question per question, and make a separate topic for each question if you've got more than one.

Comment: Here is a description on how IEEE-754 floating point numbers are stored: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985